# Reading an argument and creating a tempfile from it to use within the script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to write a script that would count the number of columns in a file.  However, I don't know what the name of the file will be.  I am trying to create a file called tempfile which has the information from the argument catted into it.

Here is the script that I have so far for the script called columnCounter:

```
#!/bin/bash
read colNumber
count=0
for i in $colNumber
do
     count=`expr $count + 1'
done
echo "column number: $count"
```

The above code works as long as I have a file name with information and type it into the terminal in the following format: cat tempfile | columnCounter.

I tried adding the two lines of the below code to create a tempfile from the
argument in the terminal and then cat the tempfile and pipe it to the columnCounter.  But this does not work.

```
cat $1 > tempfile
cat tempfile | columnCounter
```

Comment: How does this count columns?

Comment: This seems like an X-Y problem.  Is your final goal just to have a script that counts columns in a file?

Comment: Will the "columns" always be delimited by whitespace?  What if the first line has less columns than another line?  Do you only care about the first line?

Answer (score 1):

In order to provide your filename as an argument to the script you need to use [positional parameters](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams)

You could use the following script to accomplish this:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '{ print NF; exit }' "$1"
```

*This assumes you only care about the number of columns in the first line.*

---

If you want to find the line with the highest number of columns you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'NF > max { max = NF } END { print max }' "$1"
```

*This will check the length of all lines in the file and print the longest*

---

Now if you want to specify a delimiter you can use multiple positional parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

delim=$1
file=$2

awk -F "$delim" 'NF > max { max = NF } END { print max }' "$file"
```

This will allow you to count the maximum column size in all sorts of files, like a csv:

```
./columnCounter , tempfile.csv
```

---

To get even more fancy we could use `getopts` to parse the arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts d:f: opt; do
    case $opt in
        d)  delim=$OPTARG;;
        f)  file=$OPTARG;;
    esac
done

awk -F "$delim" 'NF > max { max = NF } END { print max }' "$file"
```

This would then be called like:

```
./columCounter -d , -f tempfile.csv
```

Comment: For the last variation, you could set `file=/dev/stdin` as a default value and also use `awk ${delim+-F "$delim"} ...` to use the default `awk` delimiter if no delimiter is given.